# How do I select part of an entity in JPA (not JPQL)?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I’m using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and MySQL 5.5.  I have two classes, Group and GroupMember.  The GroupMember class links to the Group class like so …

```
public class GroupMember
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private Group group;
```

How do I write a JPA query such that I get all the Groups a user is in?  I’m having trouble selecting the “Group”s only, as the criteria clause is built around GroupMember objects …

```
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<GroupMember> criteria = builder.createQuery(GroupMember.class);
    final Root<GroupMember> groupMemberRoot = criteria.from(GroupMember.class);
    criteria.multiselect(groupMemberRoot.get(GroupMember_.group)).where(builder.equal(groupMemberRoot.get(GroupMember_.user), user));
    TypedQuery<Group> results = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);  // doesn’t compile
```

The last line doesn't compile, hoping someone knows what the proper syntax is.

Comment: doesn't compile with some compiler error message presumably ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you have to create a `CriteriaQuery<Group>`. Try this:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Group> criteria = builder.createQuery(Group.class);
final Root<GroupMember> groupMemberRoot = criteria.from(GroupMember.class);
criteria.select(groupMemberRoot.get(GroupMember_.group));
criteria.where(builder.equal(groupMemberRoot.get(GroupMember_.user), user));
TypedQuery<Group> results = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```